# Recording Microphone creates 1KB files

Tags: c#, audio, wav

Iam trying to create an application that records my self, saves every 5 Minutes and starts a new recording. To do that i first need to figure out how to record my self via C#

From various google searches I found a tutorial which in the end did lead me to this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;



namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern long mciSendString(string Command, string ReturnString, int ReturnLength, IntPtr Callback);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mciSendString("open new type WAVEAudio alias recsound", "", 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            mciSendString("record recsound", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mciSendString("save recsound C://temp.wav", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            mciSendString("close recsound", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
}
```

It works so far, as that i do get .wav files named in the desired location, however it allways has a size of 1KB leading me to think that i do not acctually start the recording maybe ?

I would be very helpfull for any hint on why this might not work

Edit: No errors shown

Comment: If every file is recording for the exact same amount of time the file sizes will be the same.  Most likely the file size are slightly different and the file explorer is rounding the file size.  Right click a file in the file explorer and under properties check the actual file size.

Comment: I guess i choose the wrong words. The file size does not change as the file is emtpy. when replaying it (no matter if i recorded 1 second or 20) the file opens in any musik player and goes to the "endscreen"

Comment: Make sure you Flush() the file before Close().  With small files you will create the file but it will not contain any data.

Comment: do you mean something like ```mciSendString("flush recsound", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);``` ?
Edit: if yes, then thats not the problem causing the mistake (tested it)